# Adding a dependency for a local JAR in Maven 1.1

Tags: java, maven

My project is using maven 1.1, and I want to add a dependency for another JAR that I build which is located locally. How can I do this?

Comment: is the other jar a maven project too? In this case why not simply install it to the local repository?

Comment: My other jar is not a maven project.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an entry in the `pom.xml` for that `JAR` and when you build the project using `maven`, just add the `-o` to the commmand. Make sure the `JAR` is present in the local `m2` repository.

`-o` stands for offline, which means it'll look up for the dependencies in the local `m2` only.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have both local and remote dependencies in my project so I can't direct it to look up only for local dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Install the jar to your local repo

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path to your jar> -DgroupId=<groupID you want to give> -DartifactId=<artifactID you want to give> -Dversion=<version you want to give> -Dpackaging=jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used the following strategy: install the file to your local repository and then add its dependency to your pom.xml.

Installation could be done like follows:

```
mvn install:install-file \
  -DgroupId=my.local.jar \
  -DartifactId=localName \
  -Dpackaging=jar \
  -Dversion=1.0-MYVERSION \
  -Dfile=localFile.jar
```

for the installed file you would need the following dependency to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.local.jar</groupId>
    <artifactId>localName</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-MYVERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: so, aren't you able to install it?

Answer (score 0):

From maven-1.1 FAQ:

> **How do I add a JAR from a non-Maven project to my local repository?**
>   If it is a JAR that cannot be uploaded to Maven's central repository because of a license, or it is private, you must manually copy it to your local repository. After picking a sensible group ID, and making sure the filename is in the format artifactId-version.jar, copy it to ${maven.repo.local}/groupId/jars/artifactId-version.jar.